# Ansible json_query to filter list of dict with different key

Tags: ansible, json-query

Here is the list of dict with different keys.

```
my_class:
  - teacher:
      first_name: 'Jay'
      last_name: 'Matt'
  - teacher:
      first_name: 'Rick'
      last_name: 'Cati'
  - student:
      first_name: 'Jay'
      last_name: 'Dito'
```

So to find out all the teacher and student who have the first name as Jay, I use the following query:

```
my_class | json_query("[?*.first_name == 'Jay']")
```

But it return nothing. How can I get the results?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it

```
- name: Test Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars:
    my_class:
      - TE:
          first_name: 'Jay'
          last_name: 'Matt'
          age: 38
      - TE:
           first_name: 'Rick'
           last_name: 'Cati'
           age: 40
       - ST:
           first_name: 'Helen'
           last_name: 'Pi'
           age: 19
       - ST:
           first_name: 'Jay'
           last_name: 'Dito'
           age: 18
  tasks:
  - name: Query person whose first name is Jay
    vars:
      query: "[?value.first_name == 'Jay']"
    debug:
      var: my_class|map('dict2items')|map('json_query',query)|map('items2dict')|list|select()|list
```

Here is the result:

```
TASK [Query person whose first name is Jay] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_class|map('dict2items')|map('json_query',query)|map('items2dict')|list|select()|list": [
        {
            "TE": {
                "age": 38,
                "first_name": "Jay",
                "last_name": "Matt"
            }
        },
        {
            "ST": {
                "age": 18,
                "first_name": "Jay",
                "last_name": "Dito"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any comments are welcome. Hope there will be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_class|
               json_query('[?teacher.first_name == `Jay`].teacher.last_name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - Matt
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. 
The point is there maybe lots of different keys in the list of dict. The sample here only has two: teacher and student. But how about 5 or 10, or even more? I know I can query every key and then combine them together, but just wondering if there are any other simple ways.